# Why can't _ be used to indicate an unused/ignored argument in a method override?

Tags: scala

Consider:

```
trait Validation {
  def isValid(str: String): Boolean
}
class AlwaysValid extends Validation {
  override def isValid(_: String) = true
}
```

yields

```
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but '_' found.
       override def isValid(_: String) = true
```

Any ideas why? Or is that just something the language designers missed?

---

Maybe it's about named argument passing but this would only apply to non-overrides as overrides auto-"inherit" the argument names from the overridden method anyway, so this can't be it:

```
trait Foo {
  def bar(arg0: String): String
}
class Baz extends Foo {
  override def bar(blabla: String) = "hello"
}

new Baz().bar(arg0 = "world")  // works, even though the arg name is blabla in Baz
```

---

**Furthermore:** `_` is allowed in lambdas, even multiple times:

```
scala> val x: Int => Int = _ => 3
x: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> val x: (Int, Int) => Int = (_, _) => 3
x: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>
```

Comment: Why would you want to have an argument that is never used?

Comment: Good point, thanks; I should have been more specific; I've narrowed the question to method overrides.

Comment: I don't see how this changes the question. An override still has to have the same method signature, so why should you be allowed to ignore a parameter?

Comment: @m-z: doesn't my example with regards to inheritance and argument make sense to you? P.S. I've also added a note w.r.t lambdas and ignored arguments.

Comment: Even if the IDE and the compiler 'did all of the right things' it is still slightly confusing to anyone reading the code what the context of the parameter is and why it should be ignored (without looking up the overridden method).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you can use parameters names when calling the method.

Scala allows you to *change* the name of a parameter when overriding (discouraged though) but you always need to provide a name for the caller to use if they so want.

Comment: thanks but this doesn't answer the question — I actually posted the exact same answer to my own question but then deleted it and updated the question — it's about `_` in overrides.

Comment: actually: do you mean when the method is called directly, as opposed to "polymorphically"?

Comment: I encourage you to have a look at this article: http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/named-and-default-arguments.html

Answer (score 3):

Here's a somewhat more detailed explanation of what's going on:

1. the reason why `_` works with lambdas is that lambdas can never have named arguments anyway.
2. in case of polymorphic calls to subclass (`Baz`) instances via references of the parent class type (`Foo`), Scala will simply "inherit" the parent class method names (`arg0`) into the subclass so polymorphic calls don't see the altered name `blabla` in `Baz#bar`;
3. however, the subclass method still needs to be callable directly as well, so it does need to provide valid names for its arguments, so `_` won't work for obvious reasons; it's also recommended that those match the parent class method names which were overridden for reasons of clarity.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's simply a grammar issue.

`_` is a special identifier in scala, and it's usage is allowed a in a well-defined set of cases, such as lambdas, partial method application and pattern match.

I didn't look into the language spec, but it's safe to assume that a method parameter is expected to be a name identifier and `_` is just not a valid one.